# Upload an audio blob to AWS S3 Using Amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, blob, aws-amplify

I'm trying to convert a Blob media to a file before uploading it to an AWS S3.

Underneath a simplified version of the code in React.

```js
const Audio2S3= async (blb)=>{
const file= await fetch(blb).then(
    r=>r.blob()
).then(
    blobFile=> new File([blobFile], "audio1.mp3",{
        type:"audio/mpeg"
    })
);
try {
  await Storage.put("Audio_test", file, {
    // await Storage.put(`${Date.now()}-${file}`, file, {
  
      contentType:"audio/mpeg",
      level:"protected"
  })
} catch (err) {
  console.log("File upload Error", err);
}

const AudioS3 = () => (
  <div>
    <ReactMediaRecorder
      audio
      whenStopped={(blobUrl) => console.log(blobUrl)}
      render={({ status, startRecording, stopRecording, mediaBlobUrl }) => (
        <div>
          <p>{status}</p>
          <button onClick={startRecording}>Start Recording</button>
          <button onClick={stopRecording}>Stop Recording</button>
          <audio src={mediaBlobUrl} controls autoPlay />

          <button onClick={AplS3(mediaBlobUrl)}>Upload Recording</button>
        </div>
      )}
    />
  </div>
);
export default AudioS3;
```

Though I managed to get the file on  S3 bucket, the file is not and audio track and unusable.
[image]

The Network tracking on Inspect Element depicts the file chunks encoding before the upload to S3:
[image]

Something wrong with the **blob** conversion to *file* I guess but I did not know how to fix it after consulting many references.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I made 2  mistakes :

1- when I called the function Audio2S3 with the mediaBlobUrl parameter.

2- When I processed teh Blob parmater in order to transform it again  to a BLOB.

Underneath the modification I made and it works fine as I got the uploaded file into S3.

```js
const Audio2S3= async (blb)=>{
const file= await fetch(blb).then(
    r=>r.blob()
).then(
    blob=> {try {Storage.put(`Audio#${Date.now()}`, blob, {
      contentType:"audio/mpeg",
      level:"protected"
  })
} catch (err) {
  console.log("File upload Error", err);
})
}

const AudioS3 = () => (
  <div>
    <ReactMediaRecorder
      audio
      whenStopped={(blobUrl) => console.log(blobUrl)}
      render={({ status, startRecording, stopRecording, mediaBlobUrl }) => (
        <div>
          <p>{status}</p>
          <button onClick={startRecording}>Start Recording</button>
          <button onClick={stopRecording}>Stop Recording</button>
          <audio src={mediaBlobUrl} controls autoPlay />

          <button onClick={()=>Audio2S3(mediaBlobUrl)}>Upload Recording</button>
        </div>
      )}
    />
  </div>
);
export default AudioS3;
```

Hope this may help.